# Display more than one image in screen

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton

I have imageView under scrollview. When i select particular image from scrollview it displays center of the screen. When i select another image, the previous image will goes off. I can't display more than one image in screen.

code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 200, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:myImageView];
}

- (void)loadNextPage:(int)index {  
    int countFlag = 0;
    for(int i=index*4;i<(index+1)*4;i++)
    {
        UIButton *imageView=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320*index)+countFlag*80+ 2, 5, 75, 75)];
        imageView.tag=i+1;
        [imageView addTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //[imageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
        // [imageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        switch ((i+1)%15) {
            case 0:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;                    
            case 1:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
            case 2:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
            case 3:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
            case 4:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
            case 5:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
        break;
        }

        [myScrollView addSubview:imageView];

        countFlag++;
   }
 }

- (void)imageViewClicked:(id)sender{
    switch ([sender tag]%15) {
        case 0:
            [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
            // myImageView.tag=1;
            [myImageView setTag:0];
            break;
        case 1:
            [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]];
            //  myImageView.tag=2;
            [myImageView setTag:1];
            break;
        case 2:
            [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]];
            [myImageView setTag:2];
            break;
        case 3:
            [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"]];
            [myImageView setTag:3];
            break;
        case 4:
            [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"]];
            [myImageView setTag:4];
            break;
        case 5:
            [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"]];
            [myImageView setTag:5];
            break;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:myImageView];
}
```

Comment: please alloc any object in ViwDidLoad..not in viewDidAppear. And One Imageview can display only one image at a time..

Comment: First of all why don't you put all images in an array, then loop through that and also why are you setting your tag on click, you can even set the tags for UIButton  while you create those. And also try to put the ViewDidAppear  code in ViewDidLoad.I am just telling you the good approach to do this..
Thanks

Comment: I added this images in camera overlay. If if put images in ViewDidLoad the images are not displaying. That's why i used ViewDidAppear. And also tag for some other functionality

Comment: add some screenshots sothat your question will be more specific